# How to modify the transmit queue length (buffer) of the network interface

Tags: macos, network

How can I set the transmit queue length for a network interface on OS X?  On linux the command would be:

```
ifconfig en0 txqueuelen 5
```

but OS X doesn't recognize txqueuelen as a valid option (nowhere mentioned in the man, nor an equivalent).  Where does OS X manage this kind of configuration?

Note: might be similar on BSD system...

Comment: Can you please explain your note? Might the answer you are looking for similar to an answer for BSD systems?

Comment: Basically, OS X is based on a kernel (Darwin) which derives from one of the BSD UNIX (FreeBSD, NetBSD, etc. I don't remember which one) and OS X uses many of the BSD tools, ifconfig and sysctl being one of them. So for me OS X is just another BSD UNIX flavour, and the command to change the network interface buffer should be identical on FreeBSD and OS X.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This might help to find and understand possible answers. Thus, +1 for the comment.

Comment: There's a duplicate question (with a few answers): https://superuser.com/questions/322027/how-to-set-txqueuelen-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the default transmit queue: (e.g to 150 packets):

```
sysctl -w net.link.generic.system.sndq_maxlen=150
```

and default receive queue: (e.g to 260 packets)

```
sysctl -w net.link.generic.system.rcvq_maxlen=260
```

To check the system defaults queue sizes for send and receive (current defaults on MacOSX10.4 are 128 (send) and 256 (recv) respectively):

```
sysctl net.link.generic.system.sndq_maxlen
sysctl net.link.generic.system.rcvq_maxlen
```

It's unclear if it is possible to set a per interface queue length. The output queue length's default is set in the [xnu] kernel: `bsd/net/if.h:#define IFQ_MAXLEN 128`

On older kernels (OSX10.7) you could to set the maximum input queue length on OSX as follows (e.g. to 100 packets) - which can be useful for tuning performance with incoming packets flows - it's the internal queue that packets are put when they come off the incoming interface:

```
sysctl -w net.inet.ip.intr_queue_maxlen=100
```